# Default argument in a generic function

Tags: typescript

I have function `zip` that has signature:

```
function zip<T, U, V>(ts: T[], us: U[], zipper: (t: T, u: U) => V): V[]
```

I'm trying to assign the `zipper` argument a default value `(t, u) => [t, u]`:

```
function zip<T, U, V>(
    ts: T[],
    us: U[],
    zipper: (t: T, u: U) => V = (t, u) => (<[T, U]>[t, u])
)
```

That produces (somewhat expected) compile error about `(T, U) => [T, U]` being not assignable to `(T, U) => V`.

In the end I've resolved the issue with somewhat ugly set of overloads:

```
export function zip<T, U>(ts: T[], us: U[]): [T, U][]
export function zip<T, U, V>(
    ts: T[],
    us: U[],
    zipper: (t: T, u: U) => V
): V[]
export function zip<T, U>(
    ts: T[],
    us: U[],
    zipper: (t: T, u: U) => [T, U] = (t, u) => [t, u]
): [T, U][] {
    /* ... */
}
```

This approach has two problems:

1. basically, signature `zip(T[], U[]): [T, U][]` is presented twice (first overload and the implementation itself);
2. implementation's signature isn't most general one, with (especially in more complex cases) may lead to errors.

Is there a better way to do what I want here? Is error in the very first attempt a compiler bug (doesn't seem to be, but if it is it'd certainly make solution simpler)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is a good one; generic type parameters are specified by the *caller* of a function, not the *implementer*.  TypeScript is happy to infer the parameters and relieve the developer from specifying them, but they are still inferred based on the needs of the caller, not the implementer. That means that whoever calls `zip()` will be allowed to choose whatever `T`, `U`, and `V` they want.  TypeScript is warning you, correctly, that the implementation of the function cannot assume that `V` is going to be compatible with `[T, U]`.  With the original signature and a default parameter, the caller is free to call `zip<string, number, boolean>(["a"],[1])`.  Yes, that's crazy, and no, you can't implement it.  So the compiler is helping you out with the warning.

---

Overloading is a reasonable solution to this issue.  Your overload signatures are good.  As for the implementation signature, yes, you should make it the more general one, keeping in mind that the `zipper` parameter must be optional.  Note, however, that you must assert that the default `zipper` returns a `V`, since the compiler still can't guarantee that is true based on the implementation signature (even though *you* know that it is safe because the overloads restrict what calls can be made).  Here's an example:

```
export function zip<T, U>(ts: T[], us: U[]): [T, U][]
export function zip<T, U, V>(
    ts: T[],
    us: U[],
    zipper: (t: T, u: U) => V
): V[]
export function zip<T, U, V>(
    ts: T[],
    us: U[],
    zipper?: (t: T, u: U) => V  // note the question mark
): V[] {
  if (!zipper) {
    zipper = (t, u) => ([t, u] as any as V); // note the assertion
  }
  const ret: V[] = []
  const len = Math.min(ts.length, us.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ret.push(zipper(ts[i], us[i]));
  }
  return ret;
}
```

This is basically what happens with overloads in TypeScript.  The compiler doesn't really understand the overloaded signatures when it's checking the implementation. Once you use overloads you are telling the compiler that you will be responsible for making sure that the implementation is safe.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Answer (score -1):

You may restrict your `V`.

```
function zip<T, U, V extends [T, U]>(
    ts: T[],
    us: U[],
    zipper: (t: T, u: U) => V = (t, u) => (<V>[t, u])
)
```

Or cast to `any`.

```
function zip<T, U, V>(
    ts: T[],
    us: U[],
    zipper: (t: T, u: U) => V = (t, u) => (<V><any>[t, u])
)
```

Comment: Restricting `V` to `[T, U]` introduces unnecessary limitation on the function interface, whereas casting no `any` — runtime hazards.